# How to use lens to access a record field behind a sum type

Tags: haskell, record, haskell-lens, lenses

I am trying to access a nested record using lenses and prisms in Haskell:

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Lens.TH

data State = State
    { _stDone :: Bool
    , _stStep :: StateStep
    }

data StateStep
    = StatePause
    | StateRun
        { _stCounter  :: Int
        , _stMMistake :: Maybe Text
        }

makeLenses ''State
makeLenses ''StateStep
makePrisms ''StateStep

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let st = State False $ StateRun 0 Nothing

    -- works, but the `_2` seems weird
        mMistake = st ^? stStep . _StateStepRun . _2 . _Just

    -- why not something like (the following does not compile)
        mMistake = st ^. stStep . _StateStepRun . _Just . stMMistake
```

The line that works leaves some questions open. I am unsure whether or not the type match by coincidence. The field `_stMMistake` has type `Maybe Text`, but what about

`let st = State False StatePause`

? I am missing the explicit `join`.

And I am clueless about how prisms work. While it seems logical for the prism to give me a tuple, at the same time I expected something composable in the sense that I can go deeper into my nested structure, using lenses. Do I have to derive my instances manually for this, maybe?

Comment: Why does the `_2` bug you? You said it makes sense that you ended up with a tuple, and `_2` accesses the second element of the tuple. Haskell's type system is fairly strict; it's not going to let you skip steps like your second example seems to be doing.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I was expecting to use `stMMistake` to access deeper down after `_StateStepRun`. The `_2` isn't exactly expressive as the original data type does not contain tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated:*  As per comments, I've fixed some errors and added a few asides in [[double square brackets]].

Here's how/why your first `mMistake` works...

A prism is an optic that focus on a "part" that may or may not be present in the "whole".  [[Technically, it focuses on the sort of part that can be used to reconstruct an entire whole, so it really pertains to a whole that can come in several alternative forms (as in the case of a sum type), with the "part" being one of those alternative forms.  However, if you're only using a prism for viewing and not setting, this added functionality isn't too important.]]

In your example, both `_StateRun` and `_Just` are prisms.  The `_Just` prism focuses on the `a` part of a `Maybe a` whole.  Such an `a` may or may not be present.  If the `Maybe a` value is `Just x` for some `x :: a`, the part `a` *is* present and has value `x`, and that's what `_Just` focuses on.  If the `Maybe a` value is `Nothing`, then the part `a` is *not* present, and `_Just` doesn't focus on anything.

It's somewhat similar for your prism `_StateRun`.  If the whole `StateStep` is a `StateRun x y` value, then `_StateRun` focuses on that "part", represented as a tuple of the fields of the `StateRun` constructor, namely `(x, y) :: (Int, Maybe Text)`.  On the other hand, if the whole `StateStep` is a `StatePause`, that part isn't present, and the prism doesn't focus on anything.

When you compose prisms, like `_StateRun` and `_Just`, and lenses, like `stStep` and `_2`, you create a new optic that combines the composed series of focusing operations.

[[As was pointed out in the comments, this new optic isn't a prism; it's "only" traversal.  In fact, it's a specific kind of traversal, called an "affine traversal".  A run-of-the-mill traversal can focus on zero or more parts, while an affine traversal focuses on exactly zero (part not present) or one (unique part present).  The `lens` library doesn't make the distinction between affine traversals and other sorts of traversals, though.  The reason the new optic is "only" an affine traversal instead of a prism relates to that earlier technical point.  Once you add lenses, you remove your ability to reconstruct the entire "whole" from a single "part".  Again, if you're only using the optics for viewing, not setting, it won't really matter.]]

Anyway, consider the optic (affine traversal):

```
optic1 = stStep . _StateRun . _2 . _Just
```

This optic views a whole of type `State`.  The first lens `stStep` focuses on its `StateStep` field.  If that `StateStep` is a `StateRun x (Just y)` value, then the `_StateRun` prism focuses on the `(x, Just y)` part, while the `_2` lens further focuses on the `Just y` part, and the `_Just` prism further focuses on the `y :: Text` part.

On the other hand, if the `StateStep` field is a `StatePause`, the optic `optic1` doesn't focus on anything (because the second component prism `_StateRun` doesn't focus on anything), and if it's a `StateRun x Nothing`, the optic `optic1` *still* doesn't focus on anything, because even though `_StateRun` can focus on `(x, Nothing)` and `_2` can focus on `Nothing`, that final `_Just` doesn't focus on anything, so the whole optic fails to focus.

In particular, there's no danger that the lens `_2` will "misfire" when processing a `StatePause` and try to reference a missing second field or anything like that.  The fact that you've used `_StateRun` to focus on the tuple of fields of a `StateRun` constructor ensures that the desired field will be present if the whole optic focuses.

Now, here's why your second optic:

```
optic2 = stStep . _StateRun . _Just . stMMistake
```

doesn't work...

There are actually two problems.  First, `stStep . _StateRun` takes a whole `State` and focuses on a part `(Int, Maybe Text)`.  This isn't a `Maybe` value, so it can't compose with the `_Just` prism yet.  You want to select the `Maybe Text` field first, *then* apply the `_Just` prism, so what you actually want is something more like:

```
optic3 = stStep . _StateRun . stMMistake . _Just
```

This looks like it really should work, right?  The `stStep` lens focuses on a `StateStep`, the `_StateRun` prism should focus only when a `StateRun x y` value is present, and the lens `stMMistake` ought to let you focus on the `y :: Maybe Text`, leaving the `_Just` to focus on the `Text`.

Unfortunately, this isn't how the prisms created with `makePrisms` work.  The `_StateRun` prism focuses on a plain old tuple with unnamed fields, and those fields need to be further selected with `_1`, `_2`, etc., not `stMMistake` which is trying to select a named field.

**In fact**, if you take a careful look at `stMMistake`, you'll discover that -- all by itself -- it's an optic (an affine traversal, or as far as the `lens` library is concerned, just a traversal) that takes a whole `StateStep` and focuses on the `_stMMistake` field part directly, without having to specify the constructor.  So, you can actually use `stMMistake` in place of `_StateStepRun . _2`, and the following should work identically:

```
mMistake = st ^? stStep . _StateStepRun . _2 . _Just
mMistake = st ^? stStep . stMMistake . _Just
```

This isn't some fundamental theoretical property of lenses or anything.  It's just the naming and typing convention used by `makeLenses` and `makePrisms`.  With `makeLenses`, you create optics that focus on named fields of data structures.  If there's only one constructor:

```
data Foo = Bar { _x :: Int, _y :: Double }
```

or if there are multiple constructors but the field is present in all constructors:

```
data Foo = Bar { _x :: Int, _y :: Double }
         | Baz { _x :: Int, _z :: Char }
```

then the field optic (`x` in this example) is a lens that always focuses on that field.  If there are multiple constructors and some have the field and some don't:

```
data Foo = Bar { _x :: Int, _y :: Double }
         | Baz { _x :: Int, _z :: Char }
         | Quux { _f :: Int -> Double }
```

then the field optic (`x` here) is an optic (traversal) that focuses on the field, but only when it's present (i.e., when the value is a `Bar` or a `Baz` but not when it's a `Quux`).

On the other hand `makePrisms` always creates constructor prisms that focus on the fields as unnamed tuples, and those fields will need to be referenced with `_1`, `_2`, etc., rather than any names those fields happen to have within that constructor.

Maybe that answers your question?

Comment: the type of `stMMistake` is `Traversal`. I guess working with that one instead of `_StateStepRun . _2` is the most elegant way

Comment: I think I should point out that when you compose a prism with a lens, you get a(n affine) traversal. A prism can be reversed to create a value, which means accessing something with a prism requires it gives you back everything it contained. This is why the generated prisms give you back a tuple of all the constructor's fields. When you project out of that tuple with a lens, you no longer can reverse the composed optic because you can't supply all the necessary data. All you have left is a traversal that will match zero or one things.

Comment: Oops, you're both absolutely right.  Thanks for the corrections.  I've tried to update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Optics generally work out more cleanly when sum type constructors each have at most one field. In your case, you could write something like

```hs
data StateStep
    = StatePause
    | StateRun {-# UNPACK #-} !Runny

data Runny = Runny
  { _ryCounter :: Int
  , _ryNoMistake :: Maybe Text
  }
```

Using a strict field and (since that field is not "small" in the sense of `-funpack-small-strict-fields`) an `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragma, you can ensure that `StateStep` has the same runtime representation as in your code. But now you can get nice field lenses into `Runny` and everything will work out nicely—no magicked-up tuples.

Comment: looks promising, I will try it out

Comment: indeed the cleanest solution